# web page responsiveness issues, width not scaling

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I just finished coding my site.Now, another problem came up.I started working on responsiveness for tablet (768px) and started with the header and I don't  know what is wrong with the code.When I try to modify it from responsive.css as you can see in that notepadd++ on the right, doesn't have any effect.The width won't change at all..

[image]

Also tried to change  the header from position absolute to static, or relative, still no result.In 100% the site looks awesome but zomed out..is a total mess.Can someone help please ? I don't know what is wrong..

Comment: please create a pen with your code so we can inspect it and stuff.

Comment: Can you show your HTML and css, we can't really tell anything from a picture.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j5m6b6ty/

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/kXmwaA

The CSS I changed is

```
.rectangle{
    ...
    /*   left: 1110px; */
    right:10px;  /* new */  
    ...
}
```

and

```
.login{
   ...
   /*   left: 1138px; */
   right:10px;  /*new */  
   ...
}
```

Hope this helps!